# EXISTS query optimization on mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization, exists

I have a big data problem with MySQL.

I have:

- a `users` table with 59033 rows, and
- a `user_notes` table with 8753 rows.

But when I search which users have user note in some dates.

My query like this :

```
SELECT u.*, rep.name as rep_name FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN users as rep on rep.id = u.add_user 
LEFT JOIN authorization on authorization.id = u.authorization 
LEFT JOIN user_situation_list on user_situation_list.user_situation_id = u.user_situation 
WHERE 
    EXISTS(
    select * from user_notes 
    where user_notes.note_user_id = u.id AND user_notes.create_date 
    BETWEEN "2017-10-20" AND "2017-10-22"
    )
ORDER BY u.lp_modify_date DESC, u.id DESC
```

Comment: What is your problem...?

Comment: Re-write as a join, to get better performance.

Comment: Drive from user_notes rather than user.

Comment: Avoid exist and prefer a Left Join, and why do you join on the same table users ?

Comment: where is the explain plan? (& need details of all existing indexes on those tables.

Comment: At very least select 'x' as opposed to * in the exists. Those saying to do a join are wrong if the relationship is one to many. You need to index user notes on notes_user_id and the date column

Comment: @JeanDoux because i want get who add this user. And im making left join and getting who add this user.

Comment: @P.Salmon thank you but this code must be from this table.

Comment: Query not wrong. problem is performance.

Comment: @P.Salmon you are right. i understand. i mean, this query in php code. before queries i cant change. Thank you :)

Comment: create index on relational colums in each table

Comment: Use JOIN user_notes + GROUP BY users.id.

Answer (score 1):

Turn it around -- find the ids first; deal with the joins later.

```
SELECT  u.*, 
        ( SELECT  rep.name
            FROM  users AS rep
            WHERE  rep.id = u.add_user ) AS rep_name 
    FROM  (
        SELECT  DISTINCT note_user_id
            FROM  user_notes
            WHERE  create_date >= "2017-10-20"
              AND  create_date  < "2017-10-20" + INTERVAL 3 DAY 
          ) AS un
    JOIN  users AS u  ON u.id = un.note_user_id
    ORDER BY  lp_modify_date DESC, id DESC
```

Notes

- No `GROUP BY` needed;
- 2 tables seem to be unused; I removed them;
- I changed the date range;
- User notes needs `INDEX(create_date, note_user_id)`;
- Notice how I turned a `LEFT JOIN` into a subquery in the `SELECT` list.

If there can be multiple `rep_names`, then the original query is "wrong" in that the `GROUP BY` will pick a random name.  My Answer can be 'fixed' by changing `rep.name` to one of these:

```
MAX(rep.name) -- deliver only one; arbitrarily the max

GROUP_CONCAT(rep.name) -- deliver a commalist of names
```

Comment: ^1 for the inversion. but: Is there any chance of more than one "rep.name" per user? did it need to be a left join? who knows.

Comment: @Used_By_Already - Good catch.  However, then I would gripe about the `GROUP BY` delivering a random 'rep_name'.  I changed my Answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your query to use a JOIN rather than an EXISTS check in the where should speed it up. If you then group the results by the user.id it should give you the same result:

```
SELECT u.*, rep.name as rep_name FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN users as rep on rep.id = u.add_user 
LEFT JOIN authorization on authorization.id = u.authorization 
LEFT JOIN user_situation_list on user_situation_list.user_situation_id = u.user_situation 
JOIN user_notes AS un 
  ON un.note_user_id
  AND un.create_date BETWEEN "2017-10-20" AND "2017-10-22"
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.lp_modify_date DESC, u.id DESC
```